# Does "pip list" show all global packages?

Tags: tkinter, pip, python-packaging

"**pip list**" command shows a bunch of packages.Packages like "tkinter"(used for GUI interactions) is not shown in that list.
Allthough running "**python -m tkinter**" in terminal opens it, **confirming that it exists**.

Comment: `pip list` will not show built-in modules.  `tkinter` is a built-in module.  That's why you will not see `os` and `sys` modules as well.

Comment: okay. but @acw1668 aren't the packages show on running "pip list" in-built as well.

Comment: No, "pip list" will show the packages installed (via `pip install` normally) inside `site-packages` directory inside Python lib directory.

Comment: @acw1668: it's officially called the "standard library". https://docs.python.org/3/library/ . The term "built-in" is used for something else. @optimistic-zia : modules can be in installed in ways besides pip, for instance included with an installer, with a system repository, or even manually. `pip list` only shows what was installed with pip.

Comment: @acw1668 yeah it was actually there inside site-packages you are right.

Comment: @Novel:thanks, it's quite clear now :)